# Diffraction from a single slit experiment and Heisenberg's uncertainty principle

Tags: optics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, diffraction

Practically how to separated between Fraunhofer and Fresnel diffraction?
Do all diffraction fringes from single slit have same peaks? Why?

Comment: Hi, your question doesn't make sense as it stands (language issue?). Can you have a go at editing it to make it clearer what you are asking? Is the question [Difference Between Fraunhofer and Fresnel Diffraction](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78908/) any help?

Comment: my question is how we can separated between Fraunhofer and fresnel diffraction

Comment: But they are already separated, see the site recommended by John Rennie. The Fresnel diffraction is obtained close to the slit, and Fraunhofer, far from the slit. More than that you can also find in the articles on [Fraunhofer diffraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_diffraction) and on [Fresnel diffraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_diffraction). As to the peaks, the Franunhofer diffraction has usually a big maximum in the center of the pattern, while Fresnel diffraction may have a big minimum in the center of the pattern.